# Find all printer on the network

Tags: ip, network-discovery

Is there a way to find the IP address of network printers? I search in google but I did not get a solution. Is there a method or application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of (any?) network printers can be joined on TCP port 9100, so you can use [NMAP](https://nmap.org/) (or other suitable software) to scan for all hosts with this port opened on all your networks.